# Why do some ordinary questions receive exceptionally high votes?

Tags: discussion, voting

I would vote a question or an answer if I could learn something new or when the answer is very genius. However, I could not understand based on what criteria the other experienced SO users (those with enough rep to vote on question posts) vote and would like to hear your opinions why some very ordinary questions receive very high votes?.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933410/regular-expression-to-remove-a-letter-and-dot-combination): AFAIK, this is a very basic regex operation even for a beginning R user who has done a little bit search about regex in R. If one or two users find this interesting and deserving votes, I wouldn't surprise. However, it currently receives amazingly/ridiculously high votes in a short period of time. I have seen many well-formated questions with quite high quality has 0 or 1 vote.

### edit

- I am not sure why I received 3 downvotes. I assume the usage of "naive" is somewhat rude and replaced it with a word that is more neutral.
- The R community is very critical, IMO. I often see some new questions receive very many downvotes and many good questions without any upvotes. Therefore, I think a 5 votes is quite high even for a well-written question from a new user (relative to other new user questions with similar quality based on my experience).

Comment: _those with enough rep to vote on question posts_ You get voting up privileges at 15 rep. They may have found it _useful_ i.e. come across the same issue and are looking for an answer. People can ask basic questions provided they are well researched and explained.

Comment: [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933410/regular-expression-to-remove-a-letter-and-dot-combination#comment86882578_49933410) sums up why it's a good question even if some may find it basic

Comment: @SurajRao, I agree with you opinion. I just didn't expect too many users  find it would be useful.

Comment: @Memor-X, so this is more like an encouragement to the new users who ask questions in a right way?

Comment: Only the voters can accurately tell you why they voted for the particular question the way they voted. We can only make a guess

Comment: @mt1022 that's a possible reason yes. just as some people can downvote a question to try and encourage them to improve the question or not ask questions like that (ie, in the case of asking off-topic questions)

Comment: Another guess: it's (slightly) better than the questions by "regular new question askers" (as Gregor commented below). Although I personally would not vote based on OP's reputation.

Comment: Well it's the regex tag. That's should be enought to explain the up vote ..

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708412/how-to-find-the-largest-rectangle-in-a-2d-array-formed-by-four-identical-corners) (IMO)

Comment: You're flipping it around. The actual problem you're describing is that good content is only receiving zero or one upvote, that's terrible. 5 upvotes you're describing here as "a lot" is really nothing special in a site visited by a huge chunk of the world.

Comment: @user202729, what is this exemple about? They are so different.. It's like linking a one line question about "get all combination of a list".

Comment: @Gimby, exactly. I sometimes thought it's unfair for those good questions with zero votes. Maybe those questions are interesting and well-written but they are unlikely to be helpful for most users.

Comment: @user202729, that link is an interesting question and requires much effort to solve. It is quite different from what I mean  naive questions that could be easily solved.

Comment: I don't really like to think in terms of fairness, that implies voting is a reward system. Good stuff needs to be voted up because that is how we separate good quality material from low quality material. That's it. If that system isn't used properly, the site loses its value. In that respect, I have no trouble with this question being voted up. "naiveness" does not imply that it's bad. Spend a little more time searching and I'm sure you can find examples of truly bad questions which are upvoted anyway.

Comment: First reason: "relevance" / "popularity", which is a semi-silent criterion for success on SO (as much as a lot of people would wish it was't). Second reason: The format is designed for clear cut answers to clear cut questions, naturally this means most of the time short questions and short answers will get the majority of the votes, not research level questions getting detailed, expert answers, though there are some exceptions. Based on that, in my opinion Stack Overflow is rather poorly optimized when it comes to rewarding deep, difficult questions

Comment: Funny you mention it, it happened to me : I asked a noob question and got 4 upvotes in like 3 minutes. Then asked a very though one... got no vote on it. What can i tell you about it ? Simple and easy to answer brings upvotes. while questions that are very hard just to understand does not attract votes... people are afraid the problem might be a corner case situation and an answer would help only the one who asked. Some questions are more "attractive" by their simplicity... but this should not be encouraged unless the question have a reel value for other users

Comment: Seems kind of evident that ordinary questions are relevant to a broader audience. This is why I think I found [another one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366276/why-do-some-ordinary-questions-receive-exceptionally-high-votes).

Comment: Trivia: this question just showed up in my "questions with lots of votes" list. What's your trick?

Comment: @Shog9, I have no idea. Maybe some threshold effects as described in Deak's answer below.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, take into account the *randomness* of the voting process. You can witness some significant change depending on the time of day, on the day of the week, the people that might or might not be interested in the question at the precise moment it appears in the first page of "new questions" list, and probably more reasons.

Some of the people looking at the question, at a specific point in time, could be more biased in favor of downvoting or in favor of upvoting any specific question.

Also, I am under the impression that voting "patterns" are dependent on "tag community". In my experience, the way JavaScript questions are voted up or down seems quite different from the way C# questions are, for instance.

It might as well be caused by the inner different nature of the tagged questions. (Example: JavaScript questions/answers are much better received if there is an executable snippet embedded).

**By no mean voting is supposed to be an automatic and uniformized process** (otherwise it would have been automated ;) )

In your example, the question was tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), these are not my usual fields, but it seems there were comments acknowledging some influence.

---

To go back to your precise topic, being *basic* is, in my opinion, not a criterion for being upvoted (or not, or downvoted).

By the way, the tooltip only mentions "This question shows research effort, it is useful and clear".

Also, usual criteria for *downvoting*, or at least *not upvoting* a question is that it is badly asked. By badly I mean OP asks a vague problem and somehow expects tutoring, or readers guessing exactly the details needed to properly answer.

---

In the particular question you linked, **there are elements present that are otherwise often cruelly missing in many questions**:

- **A question precise enough** to be answered simply (and I am under the impression that OP has simplified even more his actual problem for the question)
- **Inputs and outputs are not ambiguous** (not too much at least)
- **Different precise attempts shown, with the 'incorrect' result clearly shown**

For me, it is sometimes a pleasure to see a question that is not too ambiguous, because we can go through *a lot* of horribly written ones (especially when you're doing reviews).

Now, if I see a simple question like that already having 5 upvotes, just by browsing curiously or during reviews, I won't upvote it more, personally.

If it had zero or negative votes, for no apparent clear reason to me, I would upvote it, as a reward for the asker doing at least some work of presenting his problem correctly.

Of course, if it solved or showed me anything interesting, I would upvote it too.

Also, I think **the fact that the user is new might very well have an influence**. For two reasons:

First, we all know how hard it is to earn reputation, especially at the beginning. **A lot of new users ask terrible questions. A good first question asked should be rewarded IMHO**.

I can very well imagine questions like this but with *only the first sentence* and no examples, no attempts. That would be the "standard first question" I usually see.

Also, **new questions can have a bit more visibility, because they go through a special review queue for new questions**.

So, in this case some experienced users are more keen to simply do this kind of "I upvote your question as a reward for being correctly asked, compared to the average ones I constantly see, not necessarily because it is *useful to me*, but because such questions are *useful to the site in general*".

At least, I would have this mindset (depending on my mood).

---

Finally, as the last opinion, I feel that there is an overall lack of voting, not an excess of voting in general! The fact that it is not distributed "evenly" or logically is something that you have to accept inherent in any process involving decisions and actions from a lot of different people.

---

Edit after finally:

On a less positive note, and though I try to always never assume bad intent or wrong behavior without a good reason, it's important to know that it's also possible that some bots or a group of people (voting rings) can try to game the system by getting privileges faster on the site, for instance to help a fellow of theirs, or become able to post some spam.

I don't think this is the case here, but I have no power of looking at the necessary data to evaluate that. And apparently, these users are a significant part of the moderators' job.

Comment: Well, nice brain dump. A nice summary of at least half a dozen different meta posts :)

Comment: Well summarized. I appreciate the point of randomness,  and of "overall lacking of voting."  The special review queue for new user posts is a very like reason. Personally, I also wouldn't upvote a question that already received what I think is enough votes.  As you said, we have to accept these facts and I am a little bit of over-reacting.

Answer (score 16):

It seems nobody has mentioned yet an important manifestation of the problem you seem to be talking about: [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) (though I don't think this is the case in the specific example you linked to). When a question is deemed "hot" by the Algorithms That Be, it gets placed in that list, basking in the attention of the entire Stack Exchange network. The massive inflow of viewers who more often than not have little to no domain knowledge will produce weird voting patterns.

In particular, the simpler the better. Elaborate questions about niche features of a language will never get as much votes as the umpteenth duplicate for something pretty basic. If you have a combination of simple but superficially nontrivial question with a simple answer, all those people coming from the HNQ list will go "Oh, neat!" and upvote. My long-standing experience is that a lot of the HNQ posts on Stack Overflow are duplicates, or just not very good. But very good questions/answers don't get enough views to go hot, and even if they did they wouldn't be appriciated by a wide enough audience to cause extreme voting.

Comment: This is more like a theoretic explanation based on social network. Could I interpret it like this: when a question is upvoted, more attention will be attracted to that post. When the initial upvote is based on a good reason, following viewers tend to respond in a similar way.

Comment: @mt1022 I'm not sure I understand your point. I'm pretty sure you need a combination of views and at least a few upvotes to make something "hot". What I'm talking about is a threshold effect: once something hits HNQ  the voting patterns are heavily biased. You seem to be talking about a smooth effect, that of existing upvotes on future upvotes. That's probably also correct but something different from what I'm talking about.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood your point.

Comment: @mt1022 I think Andras is talking about certain questions that are bumped to the named list "Hot Network Question", and when this happens (and this was probably *not* the case in your linked example), you can reach tens of votes in less than a day, because of the exceptional visibility (visible from the StackExchange homepage, and in a frame on every questions in the whole stackExchange network. 
A bit like this question has been featured in the Hot Meta Posts, and now votes are changing much more rapidly.

Comment: This is especially visible when some of the potentially more subjective exchanges show up in HNQ. Politics.SE seems especially hard hit.

Answer (score 8):

There is a huge number of users that are still learning basics, very low experience. So their problems are usually *ordinary* problems. Upvoting this kind of question is the same as "I'm suffering this problem too". You know, many people uses "likes", the equivalent to upvoting. In my opinion it's a emotional response, humans are social beings.

A quick search in SO may offer short answers, easy to read and understand. The user likes it and upvote.

Hard subjects likely belong to more experienced users, whose amount is much more less than unexperienced users. So, if a difficult question has many upvotes it's due to a very good matter, well wordered, and very few results in a search. Same for answers.

Comment: Absolutely. Users aren't usually scholars that come here to appreciate how well the question happens to fit with the norms of the site. They are people searching for a solution for a practical problem they have at work.

Answer (score 1):

I can speak for myself: when I have a problem that baffles me or my team and search for a solution, when I come upon a question that matches my problem I often vote it up, and also the solutions that find favor in my eyes. I do not care very much as to the ordinariness of the question.